# Why sending JSON data via POST (ajax) returns null parameter?

Tags: ajax, post, asp.net-ajax

Good afternoon everybody :)

I am working on asp.net mvc application.
I am using JQuery DataTable in order to show my data.
Actually, my ajax Post request calls a controller method which has to receive some parameters.
The problem is that they are null. I also have the Post 500 error :(

Here is my class:

```
public class ClientSelectionFiltersViewModel
    {
        public bool StrictFilteringContractTypes { get; set; }
        public string ContractTypes { get; set; }
        public string PaymentChoices { get; set; }
        public string PopulationTypes { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is a part of cshtml view:

```
@model ClientSelectionViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Sélection des clients";
}

<link href="~/lib/datatables/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h3><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list mr-3"></i> Sélection des clients</h3>
<div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger mt-2"></div>

<div id="filters">
    <form method="post" asp-action="facturationWithFilters">
     <!--some code here-->...
    </form>
    <button id="btn-filter-clients" class="btn atmb-btn-blue"><i class="fas fa-filter fa-fw mr-2"></i>Filtrer les clients</button>

</div>


    <div id="client-selection" class="mt-2">

        <div class="mb-1">
            <a id="btn-send-selection" class="btn float-right atmb-btn-red">
                <i class="fas fa-feather-alt fa-fw mr-2"></i>Lancer la facturation pour les utilisateurs sélectionnés
            </a>
        </div>

        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-sm table-bordered"
               id="tableServerSide"
               style="width:100%;">
            <thead class="thead-dark text-white">
                <tr>
                    <th>Cocher</th>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Numéro de client</th>
                    <th>Types de contrats</th>
                    <th>Moyen de paiement</th>
                    <th>Population</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>



@section Scripts {

    <!--scripts DataTable-->
    <script src="~/js/modal.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/datatables/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <!--script pour la gestion de DataTable-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#btn-filter-clients').click(function () {

            console.log($("#contractFilter").val());    //ok I get my values
            console.log($("#paymentFilter").val());     //ok I get my values
            console.log($("#populationFilter").val());  //ok I get my values
          
                console.log("début Data Table");
                $("#tableServerSide").DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,  
                    "filter": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "/clientselection/ajaxpostcall",
                        "type": "POST",
                        "datatype": "json",
                        "data": JSON.stringify({
                            filters: {
                                "ContractTypes": $("#contractFilter").val(),
                                "PaymentChoices": $("#paymentFilter").val(),
                                "PopulationTypes": $("#populationFilter").val(),
                                "StrictFilteringContractTypes": $("#StrictFilteringContractTypes").is(":checked")
                            }
                        }),
                        "contentType": "application/json",
                        "success": function (response) {
                            if (response != null) {
                                alert("Name : " + response.Name + ", Designation : " + response.Designation + ", Location :" + response.Location);
                            } else {
                                alert("Something went wrong");
                            }
                        },
                        "failure": function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        },
                        "error": function (response) {
                            alert(response.responseText);
                        }
                    },
                    "columns": [ // on définit les colonnes du tableau
                        {
                            //Cases cocher
                            "data": null,
                            "className": "col-checkbox",
                            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                var checkId = 'check' + row.id;
                                var isChecked = selectedIds.includes(checkId) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
                                var checkbox = '<input id="' + checkId + '" type="checkbox" '
                                    + isChecked
                                    + ' class="server-checkbox" /> ';
                                /*
                                 <td class="col-checkbox sorting_1">
                                        <input id="check0" type="checkbox" class="server-checkbox">
                                 </td>
                                 */
                                return checkbox;
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            //Numéro de client
                            "data": "id",
                            "className": "col-id"
                        },
                        {
                            //Types de contrats
                            "data": "contractstypes",
                            "className": "col-contractstypes",
                            "render": function (data, type, row) {
                                var chaine = string.Join(", ", row.value);
                                return chaine;
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            //Moyen de paiement PaymentChoice
                            "data": "paymentchoice",
                            "className": "col-paymentchoice"
                        },
                        {
                            //Population PopulationType
                            "data": "populationtype",
                            "className": "col-populationtype"
                        }
                    ]
                });
            
        });

    </script>
}
```

Here is my controller method:

```
 [HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> AjaxPostCall(ClientSelectionFiltersViewModel filters)
        {
            //some code here....
            return Json(result);
        }
```

I red at least 6 solutions which didn't work for me such as :

1. in ajax:

   "data": JSON.stringify({
   filters: {
   ContractTypes: $("#contractFilter").val(),
   PaymentChoices: $("#paymentFilter").val(),
   PopulationTypes: $("#populationFilter").val(),
   StrictFilteringContractTypes: $("#StrictFilteringContractTypes").is(":checked")
   }
   }),

and then in the controller :

```
[HttpPost]
            public async Task<JsonResult> AjaxPostCall([FromBody] ClientSelectionFiltersViewModel filters)
            {
                //some code here....
                return Json(result);
            }
```

2. don't specify the `"contentType": "application/json",`
3. use different syntax of my json data with or without " "
   ...

Can you please tell me how to fix it?
Thanks I a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You won't likely need [FromBody] on your action; try changing your JSON.stringify to:

```
"data": JSON.stringify({
   "ContractTypes": $("#contractFilter").val(),
   "PaymentChoices": $("#paymentFilter").val(),
   "PopulationTypes": $("#populationFilter").val(),
   "StrictFilteringContractTypes": $("#StrictFilteringContractTypes").is(":checked")
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me :

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> AjaxPostCall(ClientSelectionFiltersViewModel filters, DataTableRequestParameters parameters)
        {
//somecode...
}
```

And in JQuery :

```
var filters = {
                ContractTypes: $("#contractFilter").val().join(', '),
                PaymentChoices: $("#paymentFilter").val().join(', '),
                PopulationTypes: $("#populationFilter").val().join(', '),
                StrictFilteringContractTypes: $("#StrictFilteringContractTypes").is(":checked")
            }

                $("#tableServerSide").DataTable({
                    "processing": true,
                    "serverSide": true,  
                    "filter": true,
                    "ajax": { 
                        //"url": "/clientselection/ajaxpostcall", //doesn't work!!!
                        "url": "@Url.Action("AjaxPostCall", "ClientSelection")", //ok because of tag helper
                        "type": "POST",
                        "data": filters,
......
```

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove "contentType"
2. Set "data" : jsonObject; without JSON.Stringy();
3. Remove [FromBody] from controller action method